# Is it possible to trigger an Azure function with Python runtime inside a Azure Logic App workflow?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-functions-runtime

I have some Azure functions with python runtime which perform data validation tasks. I want to trigger the Azure functions inside a Logic App workflow. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible to develop your function in Python, deploy it to azure function and use it in the logic app (consumption), though currently I am having problem with reading it from Logic Apps. Previously I used Python 3.7 and AF V1, now 3.10 and AF3.10

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. The function has to run .NET or JavaScript.

From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=consumption#prerequisites) you can read : *"New function apps must use either the .NET or JavaScript as the runtime stack"*